# Is the player being bribed allowed to see how much cash is offered?

Tags: power-struggle

In Power Struggle, to bribe a player, you put money secretly in a folder and pass it to the player you want to bribe.

Can the player who is being bribed see how much is offered?

If not, what is the point of offering more than 50,000?
If yes, what is the point of secrecy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player who is being bribed can see the offer (in page 11 of the manual, the example shows that the player sees the offer). However, other players cannot see it and then it is secret from them.